# Split Distinct column Values into Multiple Columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Time-Series Data Frame in the below sample:

```
Date         Ticker      Price
2018-01-01    AAA        100
2018-01-01    BBB        200
2018-01-01    CCC        1000
2018-01-01    DDD        3000
2018-01-02    BBB        201
2018-01-02    CCC        1001
```

I want to obtain Unique values of "Ticker" column and convert the unique tickers into the dataframe columns. My data frame is supposed to look like the below

```
Date          AAA      BBB    CCC    DDD
2018-01-01    100      200    1000   3000
2018-01-02    NaN      201    1001   NaN
```

I am a bit new to Python, and yet to find a way to get around it. Could anyone suggest an efficient solution because I am dealing about 1M such rows at a time and need a solution that works faster was well.
Thanx in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table`:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values = 'Price', index='Date', columns = 'Ticker').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Dataframe:

```
         Date Ticker  Price
0  2018-01-01    AAA    100
1  2018-01-01    BBB    200
2  2018-01-01    CCC   1000
3  2018-01-01    DDD   3000
4  2018-01-02    BBB    201
5  2018-01-02    CCC   1001
```

Output:

```
              Date    AAA    BBB     CCC     DDD
0       2018-01-01  100.0  200.0  1000.0  3000.0
1       2018-01-02    NaN  201.0  1001.0     NaN
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: You are welcome :)